# How should i include space between name and number and make them in 2 columns in excel

Tags: excel, csv, notepad++

I have tried different ways to include space between `name` and `number` in notepad++ excel etc. Please suggest me to sort out my problem to make `2` columns in excel.

I have a list of contacts like :

```
Name contact
abcd+1234
xyz+789
efgh+3456
```

I want that to be

```
Name       Contact
abcd        +1234
xyz          +789
efgh         +3456
```

Comment: If Excel, use text to columns

Answer (score 2):

The steps to do this in excel are:

1. Highlight the column containing the values
2. From the Data ribbon, select 'Text to columns'
3. Select the 'delimited' radio button and click 'next'
4. Uncheck 'Tab' and instead check the box for 'Other'
5. Within the text field for 'Other' type +
6. Click 'Finish'

Pictures of each step follow:

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

[image: Step 5]

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++, just enable reuglar expressions in search box (after you hit Ctrl+F) and enter such regex: `(.+)[+](.+)` and in `Replace` paste: `\1 + \2`.